# Can I say "I sent her a message about"?

Tags: sentence-usage

Can I say "I sent her a message about"? I'm asking it because I saw on Google there are only 7000 results.

I have two questions about this issue:

1. Should it not be very common sentence, or maybe there is another way -more common- to express this idea?
2. Is it correct to say "I sent her message about" without inserting something after the word "about"?

Comment: Do you mean 'message'? and I think context is needed. If you're following up on a message sent earlier by speaking to the recipient directly then "I sent you a message earlier" is more appropriate.

Comment: Are you sure you Googled it correctly? I'm finding almost [7,000 results](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22I+sent+her+a+message+about%22) for `"I sent her a message about"`. That phrasing sounds fine to me.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Maybe I wrote "massage"... In any case, is it correct to say "I sent her a message about" (without inserting something after the word "about"). 
By the way, 7000 results is it not few? it should be very common sentence. not?

Comment: You sent her a message about what? It's not a complete sentence as you've written it. What are you trying to express by including "about" instead of just saying "I sent her a message."?

Comment: I thought it very strange that you only received 7,000 hits on Google, so I checked for myself and... for [***"I sent her a message about***"](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22I+sent+her+a+message+about%22) there are **21,400 results**, but in Google Books [**only 11 hits**](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22I+sent+her+a+message+about%22&tbm=bks&start=10). It's always better to check the grammaticality of expressions using GBooks, the results are more helpful and reliable.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that you probably mean "I sent **her** a **message** about [insert some topic here]". A **massage** is what you call it when someone rubs your body to relax your muscles. You do not usually send someone a massage (I suppose you might be able to hire a massage therapist to go to someone's house as a gift...but other than that...). **here** is an adverb (that is, it modifies a verb) meaning that the action is taking place in your immediate location (it is raining here, there are a lot of loud noises here). her is the appropriate pronoun for referring to a female.

Answer (score 2):

No, **I sent her a message about** is not a complete sentence.

The reason is: **about** functions here as a preposition, introducing a prepositional phrase. The word **about** says to the listener that what's coming next is the topic of the message. It's as if the word **about** promises the listener that the sentence will say the topic of the message, and then the sentence breaks the promise.

To complete the sentence, you would say something like this:

> I sent her a message about dinner.

Comment: maybe "about THE dinner". The word which comes after "about" needs an article. not?

Comment: @Dory **About** doesn't require its object to have an article. It depends on the object. "A message about dinner" would likely mean tonight's dinner. "A message about the dinner" would mean a special dinner that you've been talking about. "A message about a dinner" would mean a dinner that hasn't been mentioned in the conversation yet.

Comment: Both of your examples are with articles: a dinner or the dinner - are articles (yes, two kinds of articles of course).
If I understand your things properly, you say that it's correct to say "about dinner" without article.

Comment: @Dory Yes. All three versions are correct and meaningful. The meanings are slightly different.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I think I missed the meaning of the third version (without an article).